# VS Code extension glsl-canvas is crashing with any legal code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, glsl, shader

The VS Code extension `glsl-canvas` is crashing with the message `Oops there was a problem with webgl` even with the simplest fragment shader, like

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.6, 0.9, 1.0);
}
```

It shows, however, any syntax-specific error if I do mistakes in the shader code.

VS code is up to date:

```
  Version: 1.77.3 (user setup)
  Electron: 19.1.11
  Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
  OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
  Sandboxed: No
```

There are few other extensions installed (Pylance, Volar, Chrome Ext) one of which is `vscode-shader` (GLSL syntax highlighting).

Restarting VS Code  does not help.

Do I need to install or update VSC's WebGL somehow? Or reinstall VSC? Or install something else?

UPD. There VS Code popup window appears showing the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')`

Comment: if the extension is crashing a good place to ask/report is the extension repo